# if variable is equal to href insert class to link

Tags: php, html, url-routing, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a nav that when the user is inside the page of the href of the link it has a color applied. So I searched and I think the best approach is to use:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

After I should create an if statement that if the url is the same as the href of my navigation it should insert a class into the `<a>` element. This class will have a color applied to it via CSS.

Here you have my navigation with html if it helps:

```
    <div id="categories">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="nav-quien"><a href="biografia.php">quien es</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="nav-biografia" class="drop1"><a href="biografia.php">biografia</a></li>
                                <li id="nav-curriculum" class="drop2"><a href="curriculum_todos.php">curriculum</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="nav-galeria" class="marginli"><a href="gallery.php">galeria</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="nav-gal-nat" class="drop3"><a href="gallery_natural.php">paisaje natural</a></li>
                                <li id="nav-gal-urb" class="drop4"><a href="gallery_urbano.php">paisaje urbano</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="nav-prensa" class="marginli"><a href="prensa.php">prensa</a></li>
                        <li id="nav-links" class="marginli"><a href="links.php">links</a></li>
                        <li id="nav-contacto" class="marginli"><a href="contacto.php">contacto</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> 
</div>
```

I'm trying to understand how to wotk with request_uri as I see its very useful. So any help is more than welcome!

:)

Comment: You are basically, asking "Do this code for me" so, it is not fesable IMO

Comment: @PHP NooB. No, I'm not asking that. For now I have a basic knowledge of how to do this and I couldnt find the ifnormation in the web. With these answers me and other people will be able to understand these codings. My intention is not that people do my code, but to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    function theUrl($link) {
        $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        if($link==$uri) {
            return 'class="active"';
        }
    }
?>
```

HTML

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="" <?php echo theUrl('/index.php')?>>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="" <?php echo theUrl('/about.php')?>>About</a></li>
        <li><a href="" <?php echo theUrl('/work.php')?>>Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="" <?php echo theUrl('/contact.php')?>>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

This is a modified version of the script I use on my site. The only difference (with my site's code), I target the first sub-directory, rather than the `uri`, which allows me to have infinite pages/content within, and keep the proper main nav link highlighted. (ie `www.mysite.com/work/`)

```
<a href="/work" <?php echo theUrl('work')?>>Work</a>
(you can't use URI for this technique)
```

Comment: I see how it works, its what I was searching for, the only problem I see is that if a link is not been selected the field class remains but with no information inside if it. Can this give me a conflict or is that not bad practice?

Comment: Good catch. I use another class in my own implementation (so I overlooked that caveat when I shared my code). A easy way to remedy `class=""` is to include the entire class declaration in the php function instead: `return ' class="active"'` (space before 'class' is intentional.

Comment: you could also add `else { return 'inactive' }` following the `if` of the function. That would ensure `class` always had a value. But I would consider that to be bloat, if your navigation only uses an `on/off` pattern. `on/off` would be better served by the CSS.

Comment: Updated my post to answer your question most directly, and eliminate the possibility of returning empty class attributes.

Comment: Yep! You were right. I began playing with else but it also had to return a value. SO you would have a dummy class which didnt do anything. After I thought of find a methd to remove the class. Such a small details as including the whole class atribute in the return and POW! Thank you for the help, learnt how the server_uri works and 3 ways of using it. Me happy!

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like this:

```
<?php

function is_active($page) {
    return $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $page;
}
?>

<style>
.active_page {
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<a class="<?php echo is_active('/biografia.php') ? 'active_page' : '' ?>" href="biografia.php">quien es</a>
```

Comment: how I combine this so I dont have an empty class if the link is not matching?

Comment: I would advise leaving the class attribute in the HTML and NOT have php determine whether it is going to be there or not from the function. If you use this function and have it output the class attribute, then decide you need to add classes to your <a> elements, then you will be in a mess and have to go back and recode a lot of stuff. Leave the class in the element. It won't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] returns:

> The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, '/index.html'.

So for each menu item, you'll want to check if $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] matches your href string.

```
<li id="nav-quien"><a href="biografia.php"
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/biografia.php")
    {
        echo ' class="active" ';
    }
?>
>quien es</a>
```

Comment: working method if you have a small nav as if in a future you want to change something you would have to one by one.